# how to create a palindrome

Tags: javascript, string

how to create a palindrome by removing 1 or 2 characters using javascript
The two letter that you remove doesn't have to be in sequence, minimum valid length is 3 letters to determine if it is a palindrome

```
mom -> true // because it is a palindrome 
moqwm -> qw //because by removing the qw we get mom
mqowm -> ow //because by removing the ow we get mqm ( the o and w are in sequence again but they because q appeared first we kept.
moqm -> q // we only need to remove q
```

I will appreciate any help even if it was pure pseudo code, I am so stuck.
I know how to check for a palindrome using

```js
string.split("").reverse().join("") === string
```

but I am not sure how to remove a character at a time. and also check that...
The order of the string matters, so I can't brute force different variations.

Comment: Given `mqowm` how would the program distinguish between `mom`, `mqm`, or `mwm` as the correct answer?

Comment: Does the order of the string matters? qowmm is also a palindrom or not?

Comment: The orders matters. so keeping the same order, keeping the same order kept me stuck. because I couldn't brute force the results. and I always have to keep track of the letter or two letters got me stuck even further.

Comment: Given mqowm how would the program distinguish between mom, mqm, or mwm as the correct answer? – It only cares about the first char so in this case it will be mom.

Comment: @FrankDax, but one could also delete "qo" and keep"w" in that example ("mqowm"). I don't get what you mean with *"it only cares about the first char"*.

Comment: @trincot, So It will move in the order of the string, and  yes you are correct for mqowm the correct answer will be (ow) because the mqm is the first palindrome created.

Comment: This needs to be WAY more well defined.  `abb` -> ?  `a` is the first palindrome created. 
 but `bb` is longer.  Is the idea to make the longest palindrome possible by only removing letters?  If so, obviously there can be multiple valid answers.  And is the idea to limit the number of letters that can be removed to at most 2?  If so, obviously there are inputs for which there is no solution.

Comment: @Wyck Yes the longest possible by removing only 2, but also the minimum length is 3, so abb is (false) because it can't be a palindrome.

Comment: The minimum length applies to the string input? The resulting palindrome? You can remove _only 2_ characters or _up to 2_ characters? As Wyck said, and other comments, the requirements for this need to be fully defined and updated in your question.

Comment: up to 2 characters. either 1 char or 2 chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion: compare the characters from both ends as you would for a palindrome check. When characters differ, try two alternatives in a recursive call: either consider the left character deleted, or the right one.

An extra argument to the function can indicate how many more deletions are allowed:

```js
function makePalindrome(str, maxDel = 2) {
    for (let i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (str[i] === str[j]) continue;
        if (maxDel === 0) return false;
        // Try by deleting char at j
        let res = makePalindrome(str.slice(i, j), maxDel-1);
        if (res) return (res === true ? "" : res) + str[j]; 
        // Try by deleting char at i 
        res = makePalindrome(str.slice(i+1, j+1), maxDel-1); 
        if (res) return str[i] + (res === true ? "" : res);
        return false;
    }
    return true; // it is a palindrome
}

console.log(makePalindrome("mom"));
console.log(makePalindrome("moqwm"));
console.log(makePalindrome("mqowm"));
console.log(makePalindrome("moqm"));
```

### Iterative solution

Here is an iterative solution, specifically for a maximum of two deletions. The idea is to run 4 attempts. In each attempt we will take different decisions on which character to delete when we find a (palindromic) difference. Here is a description of the four attempts:

1. For each of the two deletions, delete the right one of the two conflicting characters
2. At the first conflict, delete the left character; for the second conflict, delete the right character
3. At the first conflict, delete the right character; for the second conflict, delete the left character
4. For each of the two deletions, delete the left one of the two conflicting characters

Here is the code:

```js
function makePalindrome(str) {
    // Perform 4 attempts which decide what to do when two characters are different:
    //   delete the left one, or delete the right one. So we have 2 options.
    // As there are up to two deletions, we may have 4 options to consider.
    outerLoop: // label for the outer loop
    for (let attempt = 0; attempt < 4; attempt++) {
        let bits = attempt;
        let leftDeleted = "";
        let rightDeleted = "";
        for (let i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            if (str[i] === str[j]) continue;
            if ((leftDeleted + rightDeleted).length >= 2) continue outerLoop; // this attempt failed
            if (bits & 1) { // In this attempt we delete the character at index i
                leftDeleted = leftDeleted + str[i];
                j++; // neutralise the upcoming change to j
            } else { // In this attempt we delete the character at index j
                rightDeleted = str[j] + rightDeleted;
                i--; // neutralise the upcoming change to i
            }
            bits >>= 1; // drop off the used (decision) bit.
        }
        // Success!!
        let res = leftDeleted + rightDeleted;
        return res || true;
    }
    return false;
}

    
console.log(makePalindrome("mom"));
console.log(makePalindrome("moqwm"));
console.log(makePalindrome("mqowm"));
console.log(makePalindrome("moqm"));
```

### Adding the additional constraint

Note that neither of these solutions checks whether the resulting palindrome has at least 3 characters. This seems a strange additional requirement, but one that can be easily added if you wanted to.

In the first solution, the second argument should be explicitly set to `maxDel = Math.min(2, Math.max(0, str.length - 3))`

In the second solution, the following `if` statement needs be adapted accordingly (changing 2 to the above expression):

```
if ((leftDeleted + rightDeleted).length >= 2)
```

Comment: I love your solutions, Can you also please post an iterative approach, if you don't mind please.

Comment: Added an iterative solution.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is ((let i = 0, j = str.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)) doing, 
is it like 2 for loops but I don't get why we increase i and then decrease l. @trincot

Comment: and this please..  (bits & 1) @trincot

Comment: The `for` loop syntax has three parts separated by semi-colon. The simple colon is just a way to do multiple things. So, this loop initialises two variables to point at both ends of the string, and after each iteration both `i` and `j` are updated to come closer to each other.

Comment: The `&` is a bitwise AND operator. Practically, `bits & 1` is equivalent to `bits % 2`. The `if` condition checks whether `bits` is odd, i.e. whether it has its least significant bit set. Then later, with `bits >>= 1`, that bit is discarded.

Comment: Can you please explain to (bits >>= 1) or why we need it in this case, and thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Imagine `bits` in binary format. It can be 00, 01, 10, or 11. The first time we get at this `if (bits & 1)`, it actually reads the rightmost binary digit. With `bits >>= 1` we shift the other digit into the rightmost position, so 00 becomes 0 (the same), 01 becomes 0, 10 becomes 1, 11 becomes 1.

Comment: Why do we care if it is odd or even in this case @trincot

Comment: To know whether we will decide to delete the left or right character. It is a choice, a binary choice, and so a binary digit serves the purpose. If this choice leads to a solution, then great. If not, the next iteration of the outer loop will use different bits, and let us make different choices.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will spend my time debugging it and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses recursive search until the length of the string is 3 (written in functional style):

```js
const isPalindrome = (str) =>
  str.split("").reverse().join("") === str ? str : null;

const searchPalindromes = (str) =>
  str.length > 3
    ? str
        .split("")
        .map((_, i) =>
          [isPalindrome, searchPalindromes].map((func) =>
            func(str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1, str.length))
          )
        )
    : [];

const filterAndFlatten = (arr) => arr.flat(Infinity).filter((x) => x);

const deduplicate = (arr) => [...new Set(arr)];

const compose = (...fns) => (x) => fns.reduceRight((y, f) => f(y), x);

const listPalindromes = compose(
  deduplicate,
  filterAndFlatten,
  searchPalindromes
);

const result = listPalindromes("moqwm");

console.log(result);
```

It's not the most efficient algorithm because it checks multiple times the same string, (that's why the `deduplicate` function). Yet it's short and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to divide the problem into smaller steps.

So, you can start by defining a function that will do the reverse of any given string:

```
function reverseString(str) {
   var newString = '';

   for(var i=str.length; i>=0; i--) {
      newString += str.charAt(i);  //this cycle will start from the last char to the first one
   }
  return newString;
}
```

Then, what is the easiest possible outcome? It's the case where the reverse of the string is a palindrome already, so we can do:

```
function getPalindrome(str) {
      if (str === reverseString(str)) return true; 
}
```

Then, for the other possible outcomes, let's divide the string into substrings and use the function reverse to check if the string is a palindrome without a char i. You can then return this char i or remove it at a time, like this for example:

```
function getPalinDrome(str) {
    if(str === reverseString(str)) return true; // already a palindrome

    var strlen = str.length;
    for(var i=0; i<strlen; i++) {
        var partialString = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, strlen);
        var reversedPartial = reverseString(partialString);
        if(partialString === reversedPartial) {
            return i; //returns the char that needs to be removed to make a palindrome
        }
    }
    return false; //can't do a palindrome
}
```

Comment: This seems to only detect cases where no more than one character has to be removed, but not where two need to be removed. For "moqwm" it returns `false`.